# Comparing positive boolean result to true and false in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

If `objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP` is 'true' in the query below, I'd like to compare `t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp` to **true and false** and return everything.

```
 return from t1 in db.UserRoles
                   where ((t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp 
                           == objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP)
                   select t1;
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: is t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp  nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from t1 in db.UserRoles
where !objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP || (t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp ?? true)
select t1
```

or

```
from t1 in db.UserRoles
where objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP && (t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp ?? true)
select t1
```

depending on the filter-function of `objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP`, meaning:

- if `objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP` value is `false` = the record might be valid depending on `t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp`: take version 1
- if `objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP` value is `false` = the record is not valid innately (no need to do an evaluation of `t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp`): take version 2

furthermore you can assign a default-value of your `System.Nullable<bool>` after `??` or go for `.GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)`

Answer (score 1):

```
       return from t1 in db.UserRoles
               where t1.Role.IsAvailableFromRestrictedIp != null && 
                     objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP
               select t1;
```

Comment: this won't compile .. there's an open parenthesis

Comment: the op wanted a conditional comparison based on `objHistory.IsLoginFromWhitelistedIP`